# Very low usb transfer speed?

Tags: usb

I am using a USB stick with a USB 2.0 port on my windows 10 machine, and I noticed that writing speed to usb device is very low, around 11-12 MB/s, despite the fact that usb 2.0 speeds can go up to 60 MB/s, and average speed of a usb stick should be around 30 MB/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using a USB stick with a USB 2.0 port on my windows 10 machine,
>   usb 2.0 speeds can go up to 60 MB/s.

60MB/sec is rare though. 30 to 35MB/sec is a more realistic value. Most external harddisks (and those tend to be faster than pen drives) are in this speed range.

> writing speed to usb device is very low, around 11-12 MB/s,
>   average speed of a usb stick should be around 30 MB/s.

Uhm. No.

Focussing on pen drives (aka 'USB sticks') those vary wildly. I have several promo pen drives which manage 5MB/sec read and 3MB/sec write. The limit on this is a the cheap pen drive. not the USB protocol.

I also have 90MB/sec pendrives which actually reach 90MB when connected via eSATA, but drops to 30MB/sec read via USB (a throttle pen drive with dual interface).   MOst of my pen drives have been selected for high speeds, and 30MB/sec really is not average. 30MB/sec is very high.  11-12 MB/s is in fact quite decent for an average USB pen drive.

Comment: Check the speed of the thing with HD Tune ==> http://www.hdtune.com/

Answer (score 0):

The writing and reading speed of any USB drives is determined by 2 main factors:

1. **The version of the USB port and drive insert (USB 1.X, 2.X or 3.X)**
2. **The physical flash memory chips on the USB Flash Drive.**

The 1. point is well known and, normally, you can see which version of the USB port you can use by looking at either the color of the USB port and drive inserts or by looking up at the inscription on the flash drive or next to the USB port. (The color originally define if a USB drive is USB 3.X, if blue, or 2.X, if black, but USB 3.X can still be black nowadays such as USB 3.0 being black and 3.2 being blue. 10+ years old PC can have USB 1.X as black ans USB 2.0 as blue or even gray. The blue color is often used to define the best/faster USB port nowadays.)

The speed for USB types are generally as follow:

- 1.0 = 1.5 Mb/s
- 1.2 = 12 Mb/s
- 2.0 = 12 Mb/s
- 2.2 = 480 Mb/s (also know as Hi-Speed USB2)
- 3.0 = 4.8 Gb/s (Also known as USB 3.0 Gen1)
- 3.1 = 5 Gb/s (Also known as USB 3.0 Gen2)
- 3.2 = 10 Gb/s
- 4.0 = 100 Gb/s

Those numbers are purely theoretical based on the kind of voltage, materials used in both the port and drive and the data compression used when transferring and extracting the cached data between the storage and a the drive. They can be seen as the hard-limit of transfer rates.

The 2. point is where you'll find the biggest difference and actually explain the high difference in prices between brands and models. To put it bluntly, the flash drive have 1 or multiple RAM chips that act as holders when moving data in and out of the flash drive (think of those as boxes holding the files). That or those RAM chips uses a micro-chips as handler to manage its data transfer (think of it as the brain that controls the hands that move the files between boxes). A single RAM chips might have as low as 256Ko of memory or has much as 4Go. The value of that RAM chips determine how many times the micro-chips will have to fill them up, send the package, empty them up, rinse and repeat until all the data is properly transferred.

So, as an example, let's say that 1 flash drive has 2 RAM chips of 512Mo and another has 1 RAM chip of 126Mo and both has 8Go of storage. The one with 2x512Mo RAM chip will have to cut a 1Go file into just 2 pieces and will be able to the whole task in a single step or, at most, 2 steps which takes barely a second while the one with 1x126Mo will have to cut the file into 9 pieces, store 8 of those pieces into its flash memory temporary, transfer 1 piece at a time, clean its RAM cache, do it again 8 times. The whole process might takes 10 secs in total. When you see the transfer suddenly hit 0Mb/s for a while, that's when the flash drive is cleaning its RAM chip's cache. The better the RAM chips, the faster that process is finished.

When you see a USB flash drive of 32Go at 15$ or a 64Go at 20$, that's usually flashdrive with a single RAM chips or a bunch of old (and weak) ones. A flash drive that cost a real 60+$ usually have multiple high-capacity RAM chips. (By "real", I mean that it's not just overpriced for its brand or for its decorative cover. If you purchase a flash drive with a cover of Pokemon or Minecraft or some TV series or anime, you know you're paying half of the price solely for that IP so a 60$ Minecraft Flashdrive is basically like a 30$ plain one.) All those "bulk" set on Amazon when you pay 5$ per Flashdrive are usually using 1 to 4 RAM chips of 126Ko to 512ko, meaning their speed is barely at twice that of USB 1.0 and that's even if they are mentioned as USB 2.0 or 3.0!